# What do the various dots and triangles mean on the minimap in Titanfall and what governs their display?

Tags: titanfall

Here is how I *think* it works:

```
Small red dots       - Enemy minions
Big red dots         - Enemy pilots who are firing a weapon?
Small blue triangles - Friendly pilots
Big Red Triangles    - Enemy Titans
Big Blue Triangles   - Friendly Titans
Orange dots          - Enemy minions (using minion detector?)
```

So my questions are:

- Do enemy pilots only show on the mini-map when they are firing a weapon with no suppressor?
- Do *friendly* pilots only show on the mini-map when they are firing a weapon with no suppressor?
- Does the [Map Hack](http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Hack) burn card let you see all pilots regardless of whether or not they are firing?
- Does the [Satellite Uplink](http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/Satellite_Uplink) burn card let you see all enemy pilots regardless of whether or not they are firing?

Comment: Normally we like to have 1 question at a time.  You might think of breaking those up into 3 or 4 questions (first 2 could probably be in the same question).

Comment: Is the xbox-one tag necessary for this question?  The question seems to apply to both the xbox-one, pc, and upcoming xbox-360 version unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, enemy pilots only show up when they are firing without a suppressor.
2. No, Friendly pilots are always visible on the minimap.
3. Yes, Map hack gives full map visibility at all times, the weaker burn card "Satellite Uplink" reveals the entire map at 10 second intervals.
4. Yes, Satellite Uplink works the same as Map hack by revealing everything, but at time interval instead of always.